# list index out of range? Iterating through NB models

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to def a function iterate through similar Naive Bayes models to save time but here I stuck at getting the result into an array as output.

```
models = {
        0: GaussianNB(),
        1: MultinomialNB(),
        2: ComplementNB(),
        3: BernoulliNB(),
        4: CategoricalNB(),
    }

def NB():  
    for i, model in models.items():
        model.fit(X_train_mm, y_train)
        pred = model.predict(X_test_mm)

        result = []

        accuracy, recall, precision, F1_score, cv = metric(y_test, pred, model, X_train_mm, y_train)

        final = [accuracy, recall, precision, F1_score, cv]
        
        result[i] = np.append(result[i], final, axis = 0)
    
    return result
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\PC10\OneDrive - Pham & Schild GmbH\github_alternative\Classification\all_classfication_ever.ipynb Cell 39' in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 result = NB()

c:\Users\PC10\OneDrive - Pham & Schild GmbH\github_alternative\Classification\all_classfication_ever.ipynb Cell 38' in NB()
     22     accuracy, recall, precision, F1_score, cv = metric(y_test, pred, model, X_train_mm, y_train)
     24     final = [accuracy, recall, precision, F1_score, cv]
---> 26     result[i] = np.append(result[i], final, axis = 0)
     27     # plot_confusion_matrix(clf, X_test, y_test)
     29 return result

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to access data in results before it exists there. `result[i] = np.append(result[i], final, axis = 0)`in this line. result[i] does not exist yet. and its not clear to me what you want that line of code to do.

Comment: also the result list is created empty every loop you may want to create that list outside of the loop.